# How to access variable from a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I want to access variables ie. distance, vertex2Position, path which in two seperate function, inside main function called getResult. How can I achieve this without altering my code or altering my code in minimum way.

```
function getResult() {

document.getElementById("vertex1").onchange = function() {
  var vertex1 = document.getElementById("vertex1").value;
  var vertex1Position = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.id == vertex1) + 1;
 document.getElementById("output").textContent = vertex1Position;
 var distance = execute(vertex1Position);  // How can I access distance in my result variable
};

    var vertex2Position = 0;
    console.log("whats here");    
    document.getElementById("vertex2").onchange = function() {
        var vertex2 = document.getElementById("vertex2").value;
         vertex2Position = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.name == vertex2)+ 1; // I also want to access vertex2Position in my result variable which is in outer function
        document.getElementById("secondOutput").textContent = vertex2Position;
       var path = getPath(vertex2Position); //How can I access path in var result
    };

var result = distance.vertex2Position; // I want to store distance and vertex2Position in result variable

document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = "test" + result + "" + path + "."; // I also want to access path 
}
```

Comment: Just declare the variables outside rather than inside?

Comment: You are creating `distance` and `path` whenever a change event happens. There is no way to access it from the `getResult` function. Instead, you will need to do the calculation and output stuff when such an event occurs, i.e. you should invert the logic and call the calculation/output function from the event handler(s). Yes, that does need considerable changes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance declaring my variable outside spits out Undefined and 0

Comment: Sounds like you're still declaring variables inside the functions. You need to declare them outside, and only outside - you need one binding for each, not two

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you show with example of doing that

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this :

```
var container = (function(){
 var distance;
 var vertex2P;
 return {
    setDistance: function(distance){
        this.distance = distance;
    },
    getDistance: function(){return this.distance;},
    setVertex2P: function(vertex2P){
        this.vertex2P = vertex2P;
    },
    getVertex2P: function(){return this.vertex2P;},


}}());
```

And then you can get and set the values in other functions like this

```
var result = function(){
container.setDistance(2);
container.setVertex2P(3);
console.log(container.getDistance() + container.getVertex2P());
}
result(); // 5
```

These are(maybe ) the best practices you can use in Javascript with this you avoid the global variables and added privacy to your variables, hope it helps you. 
P.S you can short this with ECMASCRIPT 6

Answer (score -1):

> In javascript, you need understand about scopes. In your code, the
>   main scope is the getResult() function, so if you want to access
>   variables inside sub functions (functions inside the getResult()
>   function), you'll need declare the variables at beginning of this main
>   scope.

Example:

```
function getResult() {
  var distance, 
      path, 
      vertex1,
      vertex2, 
      vertex1Position,
      vertex2Position = 0;

  document.getElementById("vertex1").onchange = function() {
    vertex1 = document.getElementById("vertex1").value;
    vertex1Position = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.id == vertex1) + 1;

    document.getElementById("output").textContent = vertex1Position;
    distance = execute(vertex1Position);  
  }

  document.getElementById("vertex2").onchange = function() {
     vertex2 = document.getElementById("vertex2").value;
     vertex2Position = graph.node.findIndex(e => e.name == vertex2)+ 1;
     document.getElementById("secondOutput").textContent = vertex2Position;
     path = getPath(vertex2Position); //How can I access path in var result
  };

  result = distance.vertex2Position;
  document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML = "test" + result + "" + path + ".";

}
```

**Note:** You're using functions triggered by "onchange" event, so your variables will initiate as undefined, except for "vertex2Position"

Comment: This will always have `distance` and `path` being `undefined` when trying to assign the `innerHTML`.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't help the OP. So in the scenario that the question is about, it doesn't work.